# Query string consist of 7 digits using LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am querying a string where the front of the string consists of 7 digits and ending with a decimal `.l`.
Can someone advise me on how to write the below statement effectively which is working. I repeating [0-9] which is not efficient.

```
WHERE TOOL = 'ABC1-1'
AND DATA_VAL like '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].1%'
ORDER BY ENTERED_DT DESC
```

Comment: Show us some data example and what should your where clause return ?

Comment: `which is not efficient` ... this is the best you can do using SQL Server's enhanced `LIKE` operator.  SSMS does not natively support regex.

Comment: Maybe SUBSTRING() and ISNUMERIC()?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm sure you know SSMS isn't the database engine - but that comment might confuse beginners :)

Comment: You can use `LIKE CONCAT( REPLICATE('[0-9]',7),'.1%')` which is the same but maybe neater. You shouldn't have a leading percent if you specifically want to match the front of the string

Comment: Why are you performing such a query? It matters. If this is a frequent query it means you have a design problem and `DATA_VAL` contains information that should be extracted to its own field. "Smart" fields that contain multiple pieces of information are a very bad idea because they're very hard to query and impossible to index. Each field is supposed to contain one piece of information. If you only need to perform this query once in a while, eg for ETL,  you can execute a regex in a Python script with `sp_execute_external_script`. This is available in all versions in mainstream support (2017+)

Comment: If this is a common query you can still use Python to extract this information to a separate field that can be indexed. Without this, your query would have to scan the entire table to find a match

Comment: Personally I'm not seeing the attraction of having to install an optional product feature and use non set based stored procedure calls (sp_execute_external_script) that perform inter process communication just to avoid having to repeat `[0-9]` seven times and to be able to use regex quantifiers instead